# How to share my Tor connection with my internal network (Tor 3.5)?

Tags: transparent-proxy

I'm using the windows installation of the Tor browser bundle. I would like to share that connection with another interface on that computer so that the entire connection with that network is piped through the Tor connection. Since we lost Vidalia, it is confusing how to proceed with this. Could somebody guide me how to do this?

Comment: Thanks to Roya for giving more clarity to the question in his edit

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. The **more hard** way: install PRIVOXY and configure it to work as a 'transparent proxy' then let other machines on your LAN point the PRIVOXY ADDR.
2. Simply way: let the program you use on other machines on the LAN and if the program permit proxy configuration, point to machine running tor server as SOCK5 port 9150, if you have not changed it on TOR server configuration. 
   I.E if your tor machine is 10.0.0.1 then let the browser, on an hypothetical 10.0.0.10, set proxy to 10.0.0.1:9150 using SOCK5 mode.

That's it !

AnteGamissu

Comment: Thank you good sir, I shall install privoxy as it suites my needs more accurately. Are there varients to this server application?

Comment: @Miphix There are lots of programs which can act as a reverse proxy, and many that are nothing but lightweight reverse proxies. I normally use the webserver Nginx in reverse proxy mode myself.

Comment: @Sam Whited thank you for your reply. I will take a look at it. If you have any solutions with Linux. That would help as well.

Comment: @Miphix I don't know any solutions that don't work with Linux (as I only have Linux and BSD installs). Nginx is cross platform and should work on either of those. Privoxy is as well if I'm not mistaken. I should also point out that NGINX is a layer 7 proxy, so you have to build it w/ the appropriate plugin to use a SOCKS upstream (which is layer 5).

Answer (score 1):

the best way - IMHO - is to use `redsocks` or IPTables/pf+TransPort and put a Tor node as a router to your network. Don't forget a DNS server too!

Answer (score 1):

Add a new SOCKSPort line to your `torrc` file, located inside the Tor Browser folder in the sub-folder `\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc`, setting it to be something like:

```
SocksPort 0.0.0.0:9250
```

Ensure you've allowed traffic in to this port in any packet-filter/"firewall" on the operating system, then configure other applications on other systems on the network to use to whatever your computers LAN IP address is on port 9250 as their SOCKS5 or SOCK4a proxy.

Note that this will mean traffic traverses the local network *before* receiving any of Tor's protection (e.g. the LAN sees what an exit would see *and* plaintext `.onion` traffic) and as such should be avoided. I'd strongly recommend against this, run tor locally where possible. LAN networks, especially those hosted using consumer routers, should be considered untrusted/untrustworthy operating environments.